# mysqli execute returns false with large result set

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL query that works fine until the result set gets large (in this case large means about 13,000 rows) at which point execute returns false.  When I check the mysqli error, It gives me the following:

Duplicate entry '13054' for key 'group_key'

There is no group_key field in any of my tables, so this must be in the temp table mysql populates.  The error occurs across several different databases.  Any ideas?

Comment: Without any code, no, I have not ideas.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a field, that's the name of a key. You'd need to look at `show create table XXX` to find the key names. MySQL requires each key have a name, but its auto-generated names are far uglier than this, so most likely this is a user-defined key name - look at the DDL for the tables involved in your query and look for a 'group' field.

Comment: I ran the show create table for all tables included in the query and there does not appear to be a group_key key in any of my tables.  When I use describe, mysql shows it is using a temporary table to generate the results.  I think the group_key is in that table and perhaps it is running out of room?  How would I look at that?

Comment: I doubt it's running out of room. That'd mean your server's out of disk space, and you'd see far more errors than just a duplicate key.

Comment: I guess I was thinking that because if I remove the biggest column from the query (a text description that was AES_ENCODEd), it does not fail.  Will post the query in a sec.